# Serial: ioctl FIONREAD returns jumpy values on OS X

Tags: macos, serial-port, posix, tty, ioctl

I am using JSSC, a serial library for Java, which internally contains a thread that periodically retrieves the port's status (using FIONREAD, TIOCOUTQ and TIOCGICOUNT ioctls) and invokes a custom method when a condition is met (e.g. when there is at least one byte in the input queue).

Even though the connected serial port is continuously sending data (w/ 115200 bps), the FIONREAD ioctl (used to return the number of bytes available for reading) returns a value of zero most of the time, before jumping to values such as 908 or 1020.

Oddly enough, write()ing to the serial port seems to "fix" this issue, in that the value seem to reflect the true size of the input queue afterwards.

Any suggestions what could be the source of this behavior? (I know there are a lot of flags and options when it comes to programming serial communication, most of which I am not familiar with. The relevant JNI JSSC code is [here](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector/blob/2.6.0/src/cpp/_nix_based/jssc.cpp).)

Thanks

Comment: Oh, and I checked: ioctl() is not returning an error.